Proving an integral estimate for $\int_0^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(nu)}{n\sin(u)}\right|^pdu$
I aim to prove the following estimate for $p > 1$:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(nu)}{n\sin(u)}\right|^pdu \leq \frac{C_p}{n}, \quad n \geq 1,
$$
where $C_p$ is a positive constant depending only on $p$.
I have attempted to approach this by splitting the integral over subintervals determined by the zeros of the function. For example, I divided the domain into two parts: $[0, z]$ and $[z, \pi]$, where $z$ is the first zero. While I was able to bound the integral over $[0, z]$, I struggled to obtain the desired estimate on the remaining interval $[z, \pi]$.
I believe the result is correct, but if it turns out to be false, I would greatly appreciate your help in identifying the issue or misunderstanding. Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve the required bound would be very helpful.

Yes. Use the inequality $\frac{2}{\pi} t \leq \sin(t) \leq t$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, and the corresponding inequality on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ obtained by reflection, to get that this integral is comparable to $\simeq C \int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\frac{\sin(n t)}{n t}|^p , dt$. Then a linear change of variables and the fact that $\text{sinc} \in L^p$, $p > 1$, gives the desired estimate of $n^{-1}$. (Note that the constant in $p$ degrades as $p \downarrow 1$, due to the logarithmic divergence of $\text{sinc}$.)
